# How to properly use the triangle equality when proving if a function is a metric on a set or not?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Prove that the function $d:\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$, defined by

$$d(x,y):=\ln(1+|x-y|)$$

Here's what I said.

It's not hard to show the first two criteria are met ;

i)

let $r \in \Bbb R^+$, $\ln(r)\geq 0 \forall r  \in \Bbb R^+$

also $1+|x-y| \geq 0$.

$\therefore \ln(1+|x-y|)\geq0$, with equality iff x=y as then we have $\ln(1)$ which is equal to zero.

ii) $d(x,y)=\ln(1+|x-y|)=\ln(1+|y-x|)=d(y,x)$

The triangle inequality I'm not as sure about.

I think we should begin by exponentiating

$d(x,z)=\ln(1+|x-z|)$ which after exponentiation yields $e^{1+|x-z|}=e^1e^{|x-z|}$

$d(x,y)=\ln(1+|x-y|)$ which after exponentiation yields $e^{1+|x-y|}=e^1e^{|x-y|}$

$d(y,z)=\ln(1+|y-z|)$ which after exponentiation yields $e^{1+|y-z|}=e^1e^{|y-z|}$

but what I'm really wondering about here is can we take that $x$ is a smaller number than $y$ and $y$ is a smaller number than $z$ and then use this to prove the necessary inequality or else how can we prove the triangle inequality here?

Comment: In your proof i), you need to say that $1+|x-y|\geq1$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. For $r\in(0,1), \ln r<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know $|x+y|+|y-z|\geq|x-z|$ by the triangle equality on $\mathbb{R}$. It follows that 
$$1+|x-y|+|y-z|+|x-y||y-z|\geq 1+|x-z|.$$
Taking log of both sides will not change the sign of the inequality since the both sides are $\geq 1$. Taking log of both sides gives 
$$\ln(1+|x-y|+|y-z|+|x-y||y-z|)\geq\ln(1+|x-z|),$$
or equivalently, $\ln(1+|x-y|)+\ln(1+|y-z|)\geq\ln(1+|x-z|)$, as required.